# Connection from flash v11+ to to nodejs using TLS (SSL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, actionscript-3, ssl, ssl-certificate

I recently started creating a server for a mmorpg im building all by myself and i used node js as the server language. I've searched around on the net and figured that using TLS was the way to go for authentification and creating a secure session over TCP/IP. Everything works fine, i created a certificate and self signed it with openssl using some commands on the web i found and it gave me the key and certificate i can use with my server. I tryed connecting with openssl and everything worked fine. The certificate node js use is in PEM format.

Thats the server code i am using:

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/server.crt'),
    //requestCert: true,
   //rejectUnauthorized: false,
};

tls.createServer(options, function(sock) {
    //stuff here
}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

Now, my game is made in flash. So i try to connect using SecureSocket that come in flash player version 10+ i believe. The problem is that flash use a DER X.509 certificate format. So i converted the .PEM file into a .DER file using openssl and loaded it into flash. When i try to connect to my server (which is both on localhost, wanted to mention incase it change something), i can see the connection attempt on my server but it instantly close connection.

This is the error from flash:

```
Secure socket supported: true
ioErrorHandler: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2031: Erreur de socket. URL: localhost"]
securityErrorHandler: [SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048: Violation de la sécurité Sandbox : file:///C|/Users/DevilCult/Desktop/Flash%20Game/tcp%20test/Untitled%2D1.swf ne peut pas charger de données à partir de localhost:8089."]
```

But like i said, i can see the connection server side even if the error says the host is not valid. I Do the same without TLS socket and it work like a charm.

In my flash code i used addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate like this:

```
secureSocket.addBinaryChainBuildingCertificate(new key(), true);
secureSocket.connect("localhost", 8089);
```

this is the key() class:

```
package
{
 import flash.utils.ByteArray;

 [Embed(source="server.der", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
 public class key extends ByteArray
 {
 }
}
```

I tryed to look around node js for information about loading the same kind of certificate (in DER format) but node js documentations says it only accept PEM format. And flash only accept DER format. And i guess using diff format on each machine doesnt work well together and that could be why my connection is dropping.

Anyway from now, i dont know where to go. There must be a way to use a DER format in node js. Ive been searching around and couldnt find anything.

Anyone have encoutered this problem before?

Comment: Don't know the answer but just saying you should realise an SWF running from hard drive folder cannot download from an internet server (localhost is local internet server). Try editing **[Permission Settings here](https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html)**, click **Edit Locations** and add your folder. Maybe that will help...

Comment: Also try placing the SWF in a simple path like **C:\test** and add that to permissions. Just thinking a folder path with lots of %20 might be a problem but dunno (usually most use underscore not spaces in a path)

Comment: I tryed adding the permissions folder to the swf but didnt change anything. I really can't figure out what is happening. I remember trying that a few months ago and saw some error about invalid certificate.. Now i cant see it so ill try to check on the certificate side for now :\

Comment: Would this be easier if you just tested it online instead of localhost etc?. I just remembered that only an SWF in **https** location can get data from **https** server. Neither `File://` nor `localhost` look convincing as secure locations (do you get a padlock icon in browser when testing the SWF/ JS / Html)? I'm out of ideas except put everything on a https server online and test there...

Comment: Glad it's sorted. You could post that as an answer, it might help some one else in future. I hear you about online testing haha. Rest now, that problem  is for another day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it... oh my gosh 4 days of pain. There is a lot of tricky part, but that was my certificate wasnt set correctly, i had no dns in it i had to set common name as localhost ... oh well :( Plus i didnt know if the addbinarychain was going to be okay, but yeah its working, i tryed without and connection isnt made. Anyway that in addition of permitting the certificate and flash allowance everywhere probably did it. Ill take my time before trying on a true certificate online... guess some problem will happen again lol